# How does `C-x z` work?

Tags: keymap, commands

Specifically, the keyboard event `C-x`, following by N `z` characters, will repeat the previous command N times.

I do not understand how this can work. As far as I understand, after the input event `C-x z`, for the behavior to be as specified, Emacs would need to somehow remap the `z` character to the command `repeat` in order for the next `z` to actually again execute `repeat'. Is this correct? If so, I do not understand how Emacs can change the keymap immediately after executing a command. If not, what is going on?

Answer (score 5):

The code is in `repeat.el`.  See command `repeat`, which is what `C-x z` is bound to.

The code uses the fact that Emacs records the current command and the last command in variables. The `repeat` code resets the variable `this-command` to what it records as the command that was previous to command `repeat`.

Note that you can define your own repeatable command by using code such as this:

```
(defun my-repeat-command (command)
  "Repeat COMMAND."
  (require 'repeat)
  (let ((repeat-previous-repeated-command  command)
        (repeat-message-function           #'ignore)
        (last-repeatable-command           'repeat))
    (repeat nil)))

(defun some-command (...)
  (interactive...)
  ...)

(defun some-command-repeat ()
  "Invoke `some-command' in a repeatable way."
  (interactive)
  (my-repeat-command 'some-command))
```

`repeat` does kind of "remap the key" on the fly.  It uses `set-transient-map`, defining the key in a transient map, and then it calls itself again.

Prior to Emacs 24 it didn't use a new (transient) keymap (such a thing didn't exist as such back then).  It just checked whether the next key/command was the same as the last.

Essentially, `repeat` fools Emacs into thinking that the current command is whatever command was used last.

Comment: Looking at the repeat defun, it also uses `set-transient-map` to allow repeated taps of the last character in the binding to continue to repeat.

Comment: @glucas: Yes. I edited the answer to be clearer about this. A transient map wasn't used originally. Using it is cleaner that what was done originally, but it's not a necessary part of the general approach behind `repeat`.

Answer (score 3):

As you guessed, for this to work, the `repeat` command needs to be able to "change the keymap" immediately after executing a command.  And indeed, `repeat` ends with a call to `set-transient-map` which makes a new keymap active (rather than modify in-place one of the currently active keymaps, it works by changing the set of active keymaps) with a binding for `z` which shadows the normal binding of `z`.  This keymap needs to be short-lived, so `set-transient-map` internally uses `pre-command-hook` to deactivate that special keymap as soon as you hit something else than `z`.